# Use a dedicated environment for drake, with r_make()

Tags: drake-r-package

I'm trying to adapt the recommendation in Section [12.7.6.5 of the manual](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/hpc.html#advanced-options) of using a dedicated environment (rather than the global environment) to interactive usage with `r_make()`.

What I did is to modify the `_drake.R` configuration script as follows:

```
envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
source("R/packages.R", local = envir)  # Load your packages, e.g. library(drake).
source("R/functions.R", local = envir) # Define your custom code as a bunch of functions.
source("R/plan.R", local = envir)      # Create your drake plan.
drake_config(plan, envir = envir)
```

for any packages, functions and plan.
When I run

```
library(drake)
r_make()
```

I get:

```
Error in if (nrow(plan) < 1L) { : argument is of length zero

Error: <callr_status_error: callr subprocess failed: argument is of length zero>
-->
<callr_remote_error in if (nrow(plan) < 1L) { ...:
 argument is of length zero>
 in process 1598 

See `.Last.error.trace` for a stack trace.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using `r_make()`, you most likely do not need to bother with `envir`. Because `r_make()` begins and ends in its own isolated `callr::r()` process, the global environment of the master session is already protected. In fact, `r_make()` is much better than `envir` when it comes to environment reproducibility, so you are already on the right track.

But if you do still want to use `envir`, please make sure the plan is defined in the environment that calls `drake_config()`: that is, the global environment of the session that runs `_drake.R`. So you can either call `drake_config(envir$plan, envir = envir)` or write `source("plan.R")` instead of `source("plan.R", local = envir)`.

Examples:

```r
writeLines(
  c(
    "library(drake)",
    "plan <- drake_plan(x = 1)"  
  ),
  "plan.R"
)
writeLines(
  c(
    "envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())",
    "source(\"plan.R\", local = envir)",
    "ls() # does not contain the plan",
    "ls(envir) # contains the plan",
    "drake_config(envir$plan, envir = envir)"
  ),
  "_drake.R"
)

cat(readLines("plan.R"), sep = "\n")
#> library(drake)
#> plan <- drake_plan(x = 1)

cat(readLines("_drake.R"), sep = "\n")
#> envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
#> source("plan.R", local = envir)
#> ls() # does not contain the plan
#> ls(envir) # contains the plan
#> drake_config(envir$plan, envir = envir)

library(drake)
r_make()
#> [32mtarget[39m x
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
writeLines(
  c(
    "library(drake)",
    "plan <- drake_plan(x = 1)"  
  ),
  "plan.R"
)
writeLines(
  c(
    "envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())",
    "source(\"plan.R\") # source into global envir",
    "ls()",
    "ls(envir)",
    "drake_config(plan, envir = envir)"
  ),
  "_drake.R"
)

cat(readLines("plan.R"), sep = "\n")
#> library(drake)
#> plan <- drake_plan(x = 1)

cat(readLines("_drake.R"), sep = "\n")
#> envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
#> source("plan.R") # source into global envir
#> ls()
#> ls(envir)
#> drake_config(plan, envir = envir)

library(drake)
r_make()
#> [32mtarget[39m x
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! The motivation for this is that I use functions (from a package) that use mclapply internally. Which causes problems with callr. I was hoping that encapsulating everything in a specific environment would solve the issue. I'll try that.

Comment: Ah, now I see the reason for using both `envir` and `r_make()`. Great workaround.